# How can I disable function keys in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

Those [classic MS-DOS games over at archive.org](https://archive.org/details/softwarelibrary_msdos_games) has brought back many memories. Being able to play them on a current computer, through the browser, is so much fun.

Since these games were certainly not written for being run through a browser, they require the use of certain keys that are already mapped to browser functions. In [Das Boot](https://archive.org/details/msdos_Das_Boot_German_U-Boat_Simulation_1990), for example, <kbd>F1</kbd> brings up the periscope view.
Unfortunately, <kbd>F1</kbd> is also Chrome's *Help* button, so it pops open a new tab with the help site. Kinda sucks when you just want a quick peek in the periscope before firing off those torpedoes.

So is there any way to disable the built-in <kbd>Fx</kbd> functionality?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637530/disable-shortcuts-in-google-chrome

Comment: Great, thanks, the node-webkit route seems to work. If you'd like  to post that as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `node-webkit` create the following `package.json` file:

```
{
    "name" : "mykiosk",
    "window" : {
        "fullscreen" : true,
        "toolbar" : false
    },
    "main" : "http://the-one-and-only-allowed.url/"
}
```

Launch with: `./nw`

All function keys are blocked. Ctrl-N/T do not create tabs. it is quite nice

One last javascript/onload trick to disable the right-click context menu:

```
window.oncontextmenu = function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  ev.stopPropogation();
  return false;
}
```